# Subtracting each element of matrix with its mean, without importing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I'd need to convert a matrix without using module, by just traversing it using for instance for loops.
I have a matrix:
`listoflist=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`
For example:
 `1 minus the mean of row[1,2,3]`
 `2 minus the mean of row[4,5,6]`
 `3 minus the mean of row[7,8,9]`
And then,print a new matrix with the new values.

Can please anybody help me?

I would need to pick each element from row(x) and column(y) subtract it by its row mean.

I can't import any module other than "math"

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Do you know how to find the mean of a list of numbers? Do you know how to iterate a list of lists? You've phrased the question so broadly that it's hard to know how to help without just doing your homework for you.

Comment: And...did you try something?

Comment: you can also checkout the mean implementation of statistics module at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/statistics.py

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a little difficult to know what part you need help with without doing the entire assignment for you.  So here are some tips that don't involve any extra libraries like `math` or `numpy`:

- If you have a list of numbers, `L = [1,11,16,14]` for example, then `sum(L)` returns the sum of all the numbers.  Also, `len(L)` returns the length of the list.  So you should be able to find the mean of a given list from that.  You may need to convert one of these to a float first though so that your final answer doesn't get rounded off.  You may want to write a separate function that finds the mean of a given list.
- To get the number in position (i,j), just use `listoflists[i][j]`.
- Using one `for` loop nested inside a second `for` loop, you should be able to iterate through each number in your array, do the calculation, and add the result to a new array.